# Sorting List of Connecting Coordinates in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of tuples with coordinates that are connected (number of tuples connected can be any):

```
[((0, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((0, 2), (0, 3)), ((1, 3), (1, 4)), ((1, 4), (1, 5))]
```

How can I sort this list so that all the duplicates removed and I have the following:

```
[((0, 0), (0, 3)), ((1, 3), (1, 5))]
```

First connected coordinates:

```
(0, 0), (0, 1)
(0, 1), (0, 2)
(0, 2), (0, 3)
```

Turned to:

```
(0, 0), (0, 3)
```

Second connected coordinates:

```
(1, 3), (1, 4)
(1, 4), (1, 5)
```

Turned to:

```
(1, 3), (1, 5)
```

I have thought of enumerating through the list:

```
for index, item in enumerate(coordinates):
    if item[index] == item[index + 1]:
         ...
```

But generally have no ideas even how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo:

- start with an empty list
- add an empty list into it

Iterate over your tuples:

- if last list in your resultlist is empty, add all elements of the current tuple to it
- if the last element in the last list of your resultlist is identical to your current tuple first element:

  - *either* add your current tuples last element to it
  - *or* replace its last element by the current items last element
- if not, add a new empty list to your resultlist and add all elements of the current tuple to it
- continue iterating until done

If you opted for *either* above:

When done, refine your results: and add each inner list first and last elemnt to a new list and that list to your final resultlist.

Code:

```
data = [((0, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((0, 2), (0, 3)), 
        ((1, 3), (1, 4)), ((1, 4), (1, 5))]

result = [[]]
for connect in data:
    # empty, add all
    if not result[-1]:
        result[-1].extend(connect)
        continue
    # does not continue current streak
    if result[-1][-1] != connect[0]:
        result.append([c for c in connect])

    # does continue current streak
    else:
         # to collect all intermediate steps as well
         result[-1].append(connect[1])

         # if you do not need to build the whole thing, use this instead:
         # result[-1][-1] = connect[1] 

# simplify result
r = [ (r[0],r[-1]) for r in result]

print(result, r , sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)], [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]]    
[((0, 0), (0, 3)), ((1, 3), (1, 5))]
```

If you replace the last element of the inner list when continuing a streak, you can avoid the last refinement step but you loose the ability to see the whole connectivity in your 1st resulting list.